# ListBox.SelectedIndex - Using Handles

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I have multiple listboxes in my interface, how do make it so that when ever I select an item in ListBox1, it also selects the item in the same row of the other Listbox (using handles)?

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    ListBox2.SelectedIndex = ListBox1.SelectedIndex
    ListBox3.SelectedIndex = ListBox1.SelectedIndex
    ListBox4.SelectedIndex = ListBox1.SelectedIndex
    ListBox5.SelectedIndex = ListBox1.SelectedIndex
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox2.SelectedIndexChanged

    ListBox1.SelectedIndex = ListBox2.SelectedIndex
    ListBox3.SelectedIndex = ListBox2.SelectedIndex
    ListBox4.SelectedIndex = ListBox2.SelectedIndex
    ListBox5.SelectedIndex = ListBox2.SelectedIndex

End Sub
```

^^^ Without using handles

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged, ListBox2.SelectedIndexChanged, ListBox3.SelectedIndexChanged, ListBox4.SelectedIndexChanged, ListBox5.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub
```

^^^ With using handles

Answer (score 0):

You're using `Handles` in both cases. In the first case, both methods have a `Handles` clause. What you actually mean is using a single event handler instead of one per `ListBox`. The quick and easy way would be like so:

```vb
Private Sub ListBoxes_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged,
                                                                                     ListBox2.SelectedIndexChanged,
                                                                                     ListBox3.SelectedIndexChanged,
                                                                                     ListBox4.SelectedIndexChanged,
                                                                                     ListBox5.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim allListBoxes = {ListBox1, ListBox2, ListBox3, ListBox4, ListBox5}
    Dim currentListBox = DirectCast(sender, ListBox)
    Dim selectedIndex = currentListBox.SelectedIndex

    For Each lb In allListBoxes
        lb.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex
    Next
End Sub
```

That will work, but it's not as efficient as it could be. The problem is that setting the `SelectedIndex` of the other `ListBoxes` will raise the same event and then that will set the `SelectedIndex` of each one again. It won't go on forever because the event is only raised if the property value changes, but it does mean that, with five `ListBoxes`, each one will get its `SelectedIndex` set five times. We can ensure that we only act on those changes that we need to like so:

```vb
Private Sub ListBoxes_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged,
                                                                                     ListBox2.SelectedIndexChanged,
                                                                                     ListBox3.SelectedIndexChanged,
                                                                                     ListBox4.SelectedIndexChanged,
                                                                                     ListBox5.SelectedIndexChanged
    Static processEvents = True

    If processEvents Then
        'Ignore any additional events raised while we are handling this one.
        processEvents = False

        Dim allListBoxes = {ListBox1, ListBox2, ListBox3, ListBox4, ListBox5}
        Dim currentListBox = DirectCast(sender, ListBox)
        Dim selectedIndex = currentListBox.SelectedIndex

        'Update all but the control that raised the event.
        For Each lb In allListBoxes.Except({currentListBox})
            lb.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex
        Next

        'Process other events again.
        processEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Of course, we could also do it with no code at all, by using data binding. You can create a single list with properties for the data you want associated with each `ListBox`, then bind that list to every `ListBox` via the same `BindingSource`. I'll use `Tuples` for this example but you can use whatever you like:

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim items = {Tuple.Create(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                 Tuple.Create(6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
                 Tuple.Create(11, 12, 13, 14, 15)}
    Dim listBoxes = {ListBox1, ListBox2, ListBox3, ListBox4, ListBox5}

    BindingSource1.DataSource = items

    For i = 0 To listBoxes.GetUpperBound(0)
        With listBoxes(i)
            .DisplayMember = $"Item{i + 1}"
            .DataSource = BindingSource1
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

That's all you need. Selecting an item in any `ListBox` will make that the `Current` item in the `BindingSource` and that will be reflected in every `ListBox` automatically.